# Executing JOIN query from Hive 1.0.0 on HBase 0.98

Tags: hbase, filenotfoundexception

I get the following exception when i execute a JOIN query, using Hive 1.0.0 on HBase(0.98) table.
Simple SELECT queries work fine.
Also, the jar file mentioned is present in the said location.

ERROR [main]: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(833)) - Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar)'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:570)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

2015-04-24 12:24:37,114 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(833)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Answer (score 0):

The hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar is being searched in HDFS.

hdfs://localhost:9000/ is hadoop hdfs address. 
You can either **Set your home path** or **Upload your jar into hdfs.**

hdfs dfs -put [*Local Jar Path*] hdfs://localhost:9000/home/user/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/